# Loading batches of images in Keras from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns, one that has paths to images and the other has string class labels.

I have also written the following functions, which from the dataframe loads the images, renormalizes them and converts the class labels to one-hot vectors.

```
def prepare_data(df):
    data_X, data_y = df.values[:,0], df.values[:,1]

    # Load images
    data_X = np.array([np.array(imread(fname)) for fname in data_X])

    # Normalize input
    data_X = data_X / 255 - 0.5

    # Prepare labels
    data_y = np.array([label2int[label] for label in data_y])
    data_y = to_categorical(data_y)

    return data_X, data_y
```

I want to feed this dataframe to a Keras CNN, but the whole dataset is too big to be loaded in memory at once.

Other answers in this site tell me that for that purpose I should use a Keras ImageDataGenerator, but honestly I do not understand how to do it from the documentation.

What is the easiest way of feeding the data in lazy loaded batches to the model?

If it is a ImageDataGenerator, how do I create a ImageDataGenerator that takes on initialization the Dataframe and passes the batches through my function to create the appropriate numpy arrays? And how do I fit the model using the ImageDataGenerator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ImageDataGenerator` is a high-level class that allows to yield data from multiple sources (from `np arrays`, from directories...) and that includes utility functions to perform image augmentation et cetera.

**UPDATE**

As of [keras-preprocessing](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/releases/tag/1.0.4) 1.0.4, `ImageDataGenerator` comes with a [`flow_from_dataframe` method](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe) which addresses your case. It requires `dataframe` and `directory` arguments defined as follows:

```
dataframe: Pandas dataframe containing the filenames of the
           images in a column and classes in another or column/s
           that can be fed as raw target data.
directory: string, path to the target directory that contains all
           the images mapped in the dataframe.
```

So no more need to implement it yourself.

---

*Original answer below*

In your case, with the dataframe as you describe it, you could also write your own custom generator that makes use of the logic in your `prepare_data` function as a more minimalistic solution. It's good practice to make use of Keras' `Sequence` object to do so, since it allows to use multiprocessing (which will help to avoid bottlenecking your gpu, if you are using one).

You can check out the [docs](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) on the `Sequence` object, it contains an implementation example. Eventually, your code would be something along these lines (this is boilerplate code, you will have to add specifics like your `label2int` function or the image preprocessing logic):

```
from keras.utils import Sequence
class DataSequence(Sequence):
    """
    Keras Sequence object to train a model on larger-than-memory data.
    """
    def __init__(self, df, batch_size, mode='train'):
        self.df = df # your pandas dataframe
        self.bsz = batch_size # batch size
        self.mode = mode # shuffle when in train mode

        # Take labels and a list of image locations in memory
        self.labels = self.df['label'].values
        self.im_list = self.df['image_name'].tolist()

    def __len__(self):
        # compute number of batches to yield
        return int(math.ceil(len(self.df) / float(self.bsz)))

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        # Shuffles indexes after each epoch if in training mode
        self.indexes = range(len(self.im_list))
        if self.mode == 'train':
            self.indexes = random.sample(self.indexes, k=len(self.indexes))

    def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of labels
        return self.labels[idx * self.bsz: (idx + 1) * self.bsz]

    def get_batch_features(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of inputs
        return np.array([imread(im) for im in self.im_list[idx * self.bsz: (1 + idx) * self.bsz]])

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.get_batch_features(idx)
        batch_y = self.get_batch_labels(idx)
        return batch_x, batch_y
```

You can pass this object to train your model just like a custom generator:

```
sequence = DataSequence(dataframe, batch_size)
model.fit_generator(sequence, epochs=1, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

As noted below, it is not required to implement the shuffling logic. It suffices to set the `shuffle` argument to `True` in the `fit_generator()` call. From the [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator):

> shuffle: Boolean. Whether to shuffle the order of the batches at the
>   beginning of each epoch. Only used with instances of Sequence
>   (keras.utils.Sequence). Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not
>   None.

Comment: Do you still need to specify `steps_per_epoch` in `fit_generator` or does it pick it up `__len__`? Also is there any relevant reason you used `epochs=1` in your example?

Comment: Indeed, the generator infers the required steps per epoch from the batch size and the len (under the hood, this is implemented in the Sequence base class). I'm using a single epoch just for illustration ofcourse.

Comment: It is also worth noting you don't need to implement shuffling yourself in `on_epoch_end`. You can just set `shuffle=True` in `fit_generator` which will shuffle instances of `Sequence`.

Comment: @sdcbr- What if the pixels are in a ```DataFrame``` already? Like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596784/custom-imagedatagenerator-for-half-a-million-images-where-labels-and-pixels-ar) ?

Answer (score 3):

I am new to Keras, so take my advice with a grain of salt.
I think you should be using a Keras ImageDataGenerator, in particular, the `flow_from_dataframe` option, since you said you have a Pandas dataframe. `Flow_from_dataframe` reads cols of the dataframe to get your filenames and your labels.

Below is a snippet of an example.  Look online for tutorials.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=False,
                                   rescale=1/255.0)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(     
    dataframe=trainDataframe,  
    directory=imageDir,
    x_col="file", # name of col in data frame that contains file names
    y_col=y_col_list, # name of col with labels
    has_ext=True, 
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    save_to_dir=saveDir,
    target_size=(img_width,img_height),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode='categorical', # for classification task
    interpolation='bilinear')
```