# Alternative for ImageDataGenerator for custom dataset

Tags: python, csv, keras, annotations, computer-vision

Following is my csv file

```
file,pt1,pt2,pt3,,pt4,pt5,pt6
object/obj0.png,66.0335639098,39.0022736842,30.2270075188,36.4216781955,59.582075188,39.6474225564
object/obj0.png,66.0335639098,39.0022736842,30.2270075188,36.4216781955,59.582075188,39.6474225564
object/obj0.png,66.0335639098,39.0022736842,30.2270075188,36.4216781955,59.582075188,39.6474225564
```

How do i load those images and the annotations to train my simple cnn?

I tried using '`ImagedataGenerator`' as follows but it didnt help...is there any other alternative?

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ImageDataGenerator` object allows to yield data either from `numpy arrays` or directly from directories. In the latter case, the labels are automatically inferred from the folder structure of your data: each class of images should live  in a separate folder. Whenever the label structure is more complex, as in your case, you can opt to write you own custom generator. If you do so, make use of [Keras' `Sequence` object](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence), which allows for safe multiprocessing. The Keras website contains a boilerplate example. In your case, your code would look something like this:

```
from keras.utils import Sequence
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
import pandas as pd
import random 

class DataSequence(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, csv_path, batch_size, mode='train'):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(csv_path) # read your csv file with pandas
        self.bsz = batch_size # batch size
        self.mode = mode # shuffle when in train mode

        # Take labels and a list of image locations in memory
        self.labels = self.df[['pt1', 'pt2', 'pt3', 'pt4', 'pt5', 'pt6']].values
        self.im_list = self.df['file'].tolist()

    def __len__(self):
        # compute number of batches to yield
        return int(math.ceil(len(self.df) / float(self.bsz)))

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        # Shuffles indexes after each epoch if in training mode
        self.indexes = range(len(self.im_list))
        if self.mode == 'train':
            self.indexes = random.sample(self.indexes, k=len(self.indexes))

    def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of labels
        return self.labels[idx * self.bsz: (idx + 1) * self.bsz,:]

    def get_batch_features(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of inputs
        return np.array([load_img(im) for im in self.im_list[idx * self.bsz: (1 + idx) * self.bsz]])

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.get_batch_features(idx)
        batch_y = self.get_batch_labels(idx)
        return batch_x, batch_y
```

You can use this `Sequence` object to train your model with `model.fit_generator()`:

```
sequence = DataSequence('./path_to/csv_file.csv', batch_size)
model.fit_generator(sequence, epochs=1, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843149/lazy-loading-batches-of-images-in-keras/51843972#51843972).

Comment: Im getting the following error, `ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 2 target samples.` . is this loading labels twice for every samples?

Comment: No, it should work correctly. I'm not sure about the exact nature of  your data and the input/output specification of your model. Do you have one input tensor and one output tensor?

Comment: this is a multi output model which will generate four x,y coordinate points